# How to reference self-collected corpus

Tags: citations, writing, linguistics

In the writing of a research paper, I've collected a large quantity of public blog posts and ingested them into a [LDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_Dirichlet_allocation) and a [word2vec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word2vec) data model. When I'm using terms from within these models, how can I reference the data source both to make it clear that this is analysis of my corpus but also to avoid plagiarism ambiguity?

As I don't know the specific location of these terms within the blogs (because the terms I'm dealing with are coming OUT of the data models) I cant cite the specific article.

What's the general consensus on citing a self-created corpus, particularly if the terms and language has been disconnected from their original articles.

Comment: I would publish the corpus as a separate data entity, probably as a supplementary material to your paper. You seem not to have a copyright problem, do you?

Comment: @OlegLobachev, Thank you for your advice. I had planned on making the corpus and data models available on a github, referencing the terms and phrases produced from the data models from that would clear up the confusion? No, there's no copyright issue. 

Thank you for your help

Comment: You are welcome. If the volume is high and no changes are in sight, a data repository like Zenodo might be more fitting the purpose.